# Spatial join not assigning IDs correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm using some of the spatial join functions (join attributes by location) to assign points to a polygon grid (that was created in QGIS using spatial tools --> create grid), but it's assigning different random IDs to points clearly in the same grid. I've tried within, contains, etc and all have the same issue. Yes I've double checked projections.

Any idea what's going on?

In QGIS v 3.8

Solution (from @Leo M): this occurred when working with the grid layer as a temporary layer. I went in and saved the grid layer as a .shp and it's now joining by location accurately.

Comment: Are the wrong IDs the ID of an adjacent grid or is it completely random ?

Comment: Completely random IDs

Comment: Which tool are you using ? Vector General > Join attributes by location ?

Comment: Yep! That's the one. And the grid is a polygon grid.

Comment: ok, and you created the grid with Vector > Research Tool > Create Grid ? Is the grid saved as a proper .shp or is it still a temporary layer in QGIS ? Sometimes I got strange behavior with geoprocessings on temporary files

Comment: Turns out I hadn't saved it properly, was working with a temp grid layer (that yes was made using create grid), and that was the issue. Now assigning correctly. Thank you!!

Comment: ok good to know :) yes working with temporary layers is the "easy way" but I got so many problems with them I always save in proper files now. Glad I could help ;)